# Classes and Base Classes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, assign, base-class

You may observe from the title that I'm new to programming and Actionscript 3. I don't think I understand how classes work. Especially in AS3. I thought they were a bunch of behaviour that you can attach to your objects and all objects with same class will show same behaviours and will have their own specific values.

I learnt about base classes now and I'm a little bit confused about these two types of classes.

I have two objects on the scene which are 'apple' and 'pear'. They are both 'item's. I want to give them variables such as 'name' and 'icon'. Since it will be an inventory system later, I want to use a class that will apply these variables to each object that I assign 'item' class. I did it with 'apple' object. It's base class is 'flash.display.movieClip' and class is 'item'. I set it's name and icon values on my timeline. Things were working fine.

I added 'pear' object then and I discovered that I cannot assign 'item' class to multiple objects. I researched a little and found out that I should give 'item' as a base class instead of class. Ok, I changed their base classes to 'item'. But what will be classes of these objects? I really don't understand and would appreciate if someone explains me in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will need to do is set the Base Class on both apple and pear to your `item` class. Then, you will set the Class to `Apple` for apple, and `Pear` for pear.

Depending on your settings, you *may* get a warning telling you that

> A definition for this class could not be found in the classpath, so
>   one will be automatically generated in the SWF file upon export.

This is not an error, and you may dismiss it.

You will also want to make sure that your `item` Base Class extends from either the `MovieClip` or `Sprite` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I don't know why but the same didn't work before. I think I didn't do exactly the same thing. Now it's fine. When I mouseover apple, it shows Apple and pear shows Pear. That's a real big step for my system.